# Reproducción en segundo plano de webview no aparece Android

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Hola estimados amigos del foros.

Les cuento que estoy desarrollando una APK super sencilla. Solo contiene un webview en pantalla completa y muestra una pagina con un par de noticia y abajo tiene un reproductor (todo esto en html).

Todo funciona muy bien, de hecho, al minimizar la aplicación la música (de una radio) se sigue reproduciendo, aun cuando esta bloqueado. Pero no puedo lograr que salga el nombre del reproductor, o la canción o al menos una referencia de lo que esta escuchando. Ya que no sale nada en la pantalla bloqueada, es como si el dispositivo no detectara ningún reproductor, pero si de fondo se escucha el sonido del webview.

Que puedo hacer ?

Comment: y cual es el còdigo de tu html? como cargas este html en tu WebView, agrega detalles, revisa [ask], saludos

Comment: @Jorgesys Estimado, disculpa por no incluir el código. No lo hice ya que considere que era algo simple. Lo puedes ver en www.mindshot .cl/player desde la aplicación mi idea es sólo hacerle webview a esa pagina. Como decía, todo funciona bien menos lo que nombre.

Comment: Si consideras que no es necesario agregar lo que estas realizando , serà dificil tal vez saber el problema. Recuerda que al preguntar debes mostrar detalles para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar de mejor forma, revisar [ask], saludos.